# How to fix a switch from going to default

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that for some reason the average of the grade does not run through the switch and i believe goes straight to default. How can i fix this little problem. must be a switch statement!

My input for grades is 76,99,85,88,83.

My guess is because my average is a 86.2? so like the decimal? I have tried to add a .0 at the end like i did for my if/ifelse and that seem to work.

```
    <head>
        <style>
            hr {
            background-color: black;
            margin: 2px auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            }

            .container{
            width: 500px;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color:   #D3D3D3;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px #8c878c;
            }
            body {
                background-color:   #EEE8AA;
            }
            form  { display: table; }
            p     { display: table-row;  }
            label { display: table-cell; }
            input { display: table-cell; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="gradecal">
            <div class="container">
                <p>
                    <label for="a">First Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Last Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Grade #1: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grd1"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Grade #2: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grd2"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Grade #3: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grd3"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Grade #4: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grd4"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="a">Grade #5: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grd5"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getGrades();" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            function getGrades(){
            // initialize variables
                var fname = 0, lname = 0, grade1 = 0, grade2 = 0, grade3 = 0, grade4 = 0, grade5 = 0, average = 0;

            // assigning varables to textbox value
                firnam = String(document.gradecal.fname.value);
                lasnam = String(document.gradecal.lname.value);
                grade1 = Number(document.gradecal.grd1.value);
                grade2 = Number(document.gradecal.grd2.value);
                grade3 = Number(document.gradecal.grd3.value);
                grade4 = Number(document.gradecal.grd4.value);
                grade5 = Number(document.gradecal.grd5.value);

            // Calculate average
                average = (grade1+ grade2+ grade3+ grade4+ grade5) / 5;
            // if else to determine what grade falls into percentage wise
                var perc = 0;
                if (average >= 90 && average <=100){
                    perc = "100-99.9 %";
                    document.write(perc);
                }
                else if (average >= 80 && average <=89.9){
                    perc = "80-89.9 %";
                    document.write(perc);
                }
                else if (average >= 70 && average <=79.9){
                    perc = "70-79.9 %";
                    document.write(perc);
                }
                else if (average >= 60 && average <=69.9){
                    perc = "60-69.9 %";
                    document.write(perc);
                }
                else {
                    perc = "59.9 % or less";
                    document.write(perc);
                }
            // switch to determine the letter grade
                var letter = 0;
                switch (true){
                    case (average >= 90 && average <= 100):
                        letter = "A";
                        document.write(letter);
                        break;
                    case (average >= 80 && average <= 89.9):
                        letter = "B";
                        document.write(letter);
                        break;
                    case (average >= 70 && average <= 79.9):
                        letter = "C";
                        document.write(letter);
                        break;  
                    case (average >= 60 && average <= 69.9):
                        letter = "D";
                        document.write(letter);
                        break;
                    default:
                        letter = "F";
                        document.write(letter);
                        break;
                }

            // display when submit is clicked
                document.write('<p>First Name: ' + firnam.toUpperCase());
                document.write('<br>Last Name: ' + lasnam.toLowerCase());
                document.write('<br>Grade #1: ' + grade1);
                document.write('<br>Grade #2: ' + grade2);
                document.write('<br>Grade #3: ' + grade3);
                document.write('<br>Grade #4: ' + grade4);
                document.write('<br>Grade #5: ' + grade5);
                document.write('<br>Semester Average: ' + average); 
                document.write('<hr>Based on your semester average, your grade falls between: ' + perc );
                document.write('<br>You have earned a(n): ' + letter + '</p>');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

expected result is "You have earned a(n): B" the result i am getting is "You have earned a(n): F".(corrected)

Also the perc and letter display in the first line when outputted, how can i only display it once??

Comment: I would suggest logging average and seeing what you get. It looks to me like you're overwriting your variables in the first line

Comment: Just did an alert and displays "F"

Comment: How can average display F? It should be a number

Comment: `case` has to be a value not a condition

Comment: I think he meant letter

Comment: not printing average displaying letter grade. also the average is 86.2.

Comment: So log average inside your switch. That's where your problem probably is

Comment: then how does this one work? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-javascript         im confused

Comment: sorry @Moon_Sun_98, apparently ranges are supported in switch..cases! was confused from the documentation in MDN and the comment. thanks for the link, its good to learn from the mistake!

Comment: I think your last edit, trimming down the question by removing the html, removed important information like how the variables are defined and assigned; so I'm rolling the edit back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the grade variables are `undefined` and get typecasted to 0
so the `average` is always `0`, hence the default`(else)` will be set even if you write an `if...else`

update the code like below;

```
        if(average >= 90.0)
           letter = "A";
        else if(average >= 80.0)
           letter = "B";
        else if(average >= 70.0)
           letter = "C";
        else if(average >= 60.0)
           letter = "D";
        else
           letter = "F";
        document.write('<br>You have earned a(n): ' + letter);
```

**Update**

The problem now is that unless the average is "exactly" 90,80,70 or 60, it will always be the "default" and give you `F`!

**Update**

Find the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ur2nvxg4/2/

Again, if you have to use switch ranges, you must have `switch(true)` and `case average >= value` in the code for `perc` I see a potential error when the value is 89.99% from the code. it has also been modified

Comment: Not sure this is the case. all the grades are defined properly, and your solution has them hard coding the grade, which is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: and just defining does not give them any value, which initializes them as undefined, and typecasts it to zero when summed,

Comment: Yes its undefined but you can see from the provided code, that he is clearly initializing each variable on the next line.

Comment: you might see that the answer wa before he update dthe question

Comment: Good answer, but no need for the (passive) aggressiveness @dhananjai

Comment: I am sorry @Geert-Jan, the question was apparently updated after I answered, and guess I just got a bit taken aback with the `hardcoding is definitely not the way to go` thing

Comment: how do i make it accept a decimal answer? sorry for late reply i am changing code and running it to see if anything works. so far it still says F

Comment: @Moon_Sun_98 check the jsfiddle in the anwer

Comment: finally got it to work but both perc and letter are displayed twice! once in the beginning and end (where i want it)

Comment: that is because you are using document.write, I can remove that.

Comment: I have another requirement do i make a new question or continue in this page?? Sorry im new!

Comment: create a new question if it is different, and search before you ask :)
please do post what you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

Some things could help us:

Why don't you console.log the average, and the typeof average?

There may be 2 issues going on here:

**1) The grade variables are not getting the value from each of your inputs.** 
If this is the case, why don't you assign an ID to each input, since they represent a distinct value for each grade.

(If the inputs are dynamically created, you can create an ID for each of them associated with their index).

Lets say that we have :

```
 <label for="a">Grade #1: </label>
 <input type="text" name="grd1" id="grade1/>
```

Now we can get the value by doing:

```
const grade1 = document.querySelector("#grade1").value;
```

console.log the value of grade1 to make sure you're getting something back.

Also, you have to convert it to a number, as I believe the value is stored as a string.

2) **Type mismatch**

If you are getting back correct values for grade, try and console log the typeof each grade, and the average.

What could end up happening is that the average is actually a string, because the grades are treated as a string.